# Powershell write-host & write-output sequencing

Tags: powershell

I need some explanation about a Powershell script that I'm writing (from VSCodium with Powershell Core v7.2). The script automates some queries to an API. I have misunderstood how Powershell handles command sequencing.

So if I write :

```
Write-Output ('## Action 1 ##')
Invoke-WebRequest ... (consider as the 1st request)

Write-Output ('## Action 2 ##')
Invoke-WebRequest ... (consider as the 2nd request)

Write-Output ('## Action 3 ##')
Invoke-WebRequest ... (consider as the 3rd request)
```

The result will be :

```
## Action 1 ##
result of the 1st request
## Action 2 ##
result2 of the 2nd request
## Action 3 ##
result3 of the 3rd request
```

On the other hand, if I do the same thing with `Write-Host` instead of `Write-Output` I get :

```
## Action 1 ##
## Action 2 ##
## Action 3 ##

result of the 1st request
result of the 2nd request
result of the 3rd request
```

Overall, how does Powershell sequence commands within a script?

*(I do think the write-host cmdlet acts like another thread or stream, but it's not trivial to understand)*

Comment: The command sequence is the same (eg. the first call to `Invoke-WebRequest` _did_ happen before the second call to `Write-Host`) - what you're observing is a discrepancy in how fast the output reaches the screen buffer - `Write-Host` writes to the screen buffer immediately, whereas PowerShell holds the standard output and "waits" for a bit, in order to make better decisions about output _formatting_. Tack `| Out-Host` or `| Out-Default` onto the end of the `Invoke-WebRequest` statements and you'll see the output printed in the expected order

Comment: Append `| Out-Host` at the end of each `iwr`.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks a lot guys for the explanation. Do you have any references about this ? i'm curious to know more in details. I tried another thing at the moment, if i set $var to my Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet, it seems that it runs "synchronous". Does Invoke-Webrequest standard behaviour shouldn't be asynchronous ? if yes, it means that it runs every command and display it at the same time ?

Comment: Any table output is delayed by format-table running in the background until it sees at least 2 objects.

Comment: I'm collecting information from 3 DCs using 3 `Get-ADDomainController` command sequentially, selecting a few columns and sorting each result, individually. By default this will result in a single list with a single header (coming from Linux this is a "wat?"). Appending `Out-Host` at the end of any of  the 3 commands will just create its own table (breaking it out of the rest) but it will not help any `Write-Host` command to be synchronously printed along with the DC information.